# Open CV: cv::LineIterator undefined when compiling for Mac M1

Tags: c++, swift, opencv, mac-catalyst, apple-m1

I have an error of `Undefined symbol cv::LineIterator::LineIterator(cv::Mat const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, int, bool)`. So I've stumbled upon this issue that I am not sure if it is a bug but I cannot figure out how to fix it or what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to compile a library that uses OpenCV 4.5.1 that I compiled myself for a Mac Catalyst architecture. The OpenCV library I compiled for both arm64 and x86_64 architectures

```
$ lipo -info opencv2macos.framework/opencv2macos
Architectures in the fat file: opencv2macos.framework/opencv2macos are: x86_64 arm64
```

However when I try to compile a library that instantiates a `cv::LineIterator line_it(mask, cv::Point(2, 4), cv::Point(10, 20), 8, false)` I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cv::LineIterator::LineIterator(cv::Mat const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, int, bool)", referenced from:
      getPointCorresp(Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const&, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1> const&, cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::Point_<float>, std::__1::allocator<cv::Point_<float> > > const&, cv::Mat const&, bool) in CMAUtil.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After more researching and investigating, the issue was because I was using 2 opencv2 frameworks, one compiled for iOS devices and one compiled for Mac Catalyst.

When I compiled the framework for Catalyst I used a flag to change the name of the framework from `opencv2` to `opencv2macos` which meant that the include headers were supposed to be like `#include<opencv2macos/core.hpp>`. However when I looked into a few more headers I could find `#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>` which explains why my project was somehow linking to the wrong framework - it was linking to code from `opencv2.framework` instead of `opencv2macos.framework` and because the two were different versions (the first one was 4.1.1 and the second was 4.5.1) I guess there was discrepancy within the implementation.